# Who is this old man in Despicable Me?

Tags: despicable-me, easter-egg

He's first shown getting out of the bus at the pyramid and he is part of the crowd when Justin is flying through the air. He's wearing sunglasses and a military veteran looking hat. Then later in the movie he is the person that gets knocked off the guard rail when Agnes screams and Gru slams into it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Does he have a name?  Do we know anything about him?  This seems like it might be intended as an Easter Egg, so perhaps the writers or producers have mentioned it at some point?

Comment: No research effort, the man is _clearly_ labelled as Will Arnett.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a prime example of the [Recurring Extra trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RecurringExtra).

These are common in animated features. In an exaggerated sense, consider [Scrat, the prehistoric squirrel](http://www.iceagemovies.com/ca/characters/scrat) and the acorn subplot in the [Ice Age](http://www.iceagemovies.com/ca/home) movie series. He has nothing to do with the main plot but keeps popping up in situations that involve the main characters.

Perhaps the overuse of this trope in animated films is due to the fact that it is simply more cost effective to reuse an existing character than to construct a new one. On the other hand, it could be used as an attention getter. It certainly seems to have piqued your interest and you most likely have had to watch the film multiple times in order to develop a hypothesis. Possibly even watched the sequel efforts to see if the trope continued.

Comment: It's probably no accident that this character looks similar to Stan Lee, so it's probably a homage to his recurring Marvel cameos.